# jQuery Autopopulate Multiple Select uses text instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a multiple select like this configured to auto-populate:

```
     <select id="multiple-select-box" class="selectivity-input" data-placeholder="Type to search condos" multiple>     
            <option id="Alabama Grove Terrace" value="Alabama Grove"  >Alabama Grove Terrace</option>
            <option id="Alden Pines" value="Alden Pines"  >Alden</option>  
    </select>
```

Upon select I realized the script is submitting the visible Text for each option instead of the value="" for each option chosen.

I tried to change var t=$(this).text(); to var t=$(this).value(); thinking that would grab the value instead of the option text but had the same results.  What am I missing?

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                        $("#bySub").submit(function(){
                            $(".selectivity-multiple-selected-item").each(function(){
                            var t=$(this).text();
                            //if()
                            $(".ml").append("<option selected='selected'>"+t+"</option>");
                        });

                        })

                $('#multiple-select-box').selectivity();


            });
        </script>
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).value()`?

Comment: .text(); changed to .value(); with the idea that value was the option value="" of the select chosen.

Comment: in jquery you must use .val() instead of the full .value() to get the value property of the input

Comment: interesting I tried that and upon submit it does not forward the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I went to check this selectivity plugin you're using and it converts your `select` into a series of `divs` as

```
<div class="selectivity-results-container">
    <div class="selectivity-result-item highlight" data-item-id="Alabama Grove">Alabama Grove Terrace</div>
    <div class="selectivity-result-item" data-item-id="Alden Pines">Alden</div>
</div>
```

you have to change your `submit` function to get the `data-item-id` property which corresponds to your original `select` `value` like

```
$("#bySub").submit(function(){
    $(".selectivity-multiple-selected-item").each(function(){
    var t=$(this).data("item-id");
    $(".ml").append("<option selected='selected'>"+t+"</option>");
});
```

**edit**

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8buu5jrg/)

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you are appending options to the select, but you have set no value attribute:

```
 $(".ml").append("<option selected='selected'>"+t+"</option>");
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the "fetch value" method of a form element in jQuery is:

```
$(this).val()
```

You might be confusing it with the JavaScript property:

```
this.value
```

...which also works. Both return an array of strings if something is selected and set to "multiple"

To follow up on your comment, I don't see your markup for the selected element with class="ml" thus it's almost impossible to debug why your form isn't submitting the values without seeing the bigger picture (i.e. it may be outside the form element). You could try adding the value property to the select element however jQuery should be able to pick up selected options missing the value property by using the text value instead.